# XAMPP MySQL Cannot connect: invalid settings

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm trying to use mysql with xampp on windows 7 and I'm getting lot of errors.

I am able to run mysql through the command prompt just fine, so long as it is not running in xampp. here are the things I've done so far:

- changed skype port settings
- changed the password that xampp uses to match my mysql password
- changed environment variables and PATH variable in windows 7
- removed all oracle database related things in environment variables and **PATH**

Of note is that I can't use xampp and mysql while mysql server is listening on port 3036. I installed MySQL server 5.7.

Here is an **image of my xampp dashboard**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7omRY.png

**Below is my mysql_error file contents:**

> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 f1c InnoDB: Warning: Using
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>   removed in future releases, together with the option
>   innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 3868 [Note] InnoDB:
>   innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of
>   small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool
>   at least up to 20MB.
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 3868 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count
>   buffer pool pages
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 3868 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is
>   disabled
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 3868 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use
>   Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 3868 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence()
>   are used for memory barrier
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 3868 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib
>   1.2.3
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 3868 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32
>   instructions
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 3868 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size
>   = 16.0M
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 3868 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
>   buffer pool
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:28 3868 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format
>   is Barracuda.
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:29 3868 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are
>   active.
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:29 3868 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:29 3868 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB
>   (http://www.percona.com) 
>   5.6.32-79.0 started; log sequence number 1840435
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:29 6480 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet
>   started
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:29 3868 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:29 3868 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>
> 2016-12-05 21:40:29 3868 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready
>   for connections.
>
> Version: '10.1.19-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary
>   distribution

Comment: in summary, your setup are consist of MySQL Server 5.7, xampp, Oracle, and Skype..? Just to be sure, without being invoked from xampp it runs with port 3306 right? however it did not work while you start it from xampp as stated in __so long as it is not being ran from xampp__?

Comment: I mentioned Oracle and Skype because they might have been interfering, so I fixed them.

Comment: well, i do believe the only one that interferes each other are [MySQL Server 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html#option_general_port) and [MariaDB that being shipped with xampp](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/#port-3306-is-configured-in-firewall). Have you tried to run MariaDB while turning off your MySQL Server services? also, just a reminder, Xampp control panel require us to run it as admin.

Comment: I'm not sure what has happened, but I can no longer launch mysql through the command prompt.
Here is a picture of my netstat -a -b results while I work this out http://i.imgur.com/GHeu7x0.png

Comment: "I'm not sure what has happened, but I can no longer launch mysql through the command prompt" - so, you can't access mysql once you turn off the mysql server service..? also to confirm things, you ran mysql as a user named "apps"...? anyway, it is better to ask this server related stuff to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gsWj5b4.png
I'm at a loss for what to do. Mysqld.exe is running in my processes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm nonplussed.

I configured mysql to login as user root with a password. However it worked when I tried to login with no password.